# Django by Steven Holzner - Is it a version/setup issue at my end or errors in the book?

Tags: django

Has anyone any experience of using the book Django by Steven Holzner? I picked it up in the library and despite being initially impressed with its simplicity I have discovered a few issues with it. I am not experienced enough with either Django or Python to know if they are issues with my version/setup or errors, can anyone provide reasons for these issues or are they just errors in the book?

I will give two examples that I found in the Chapter 2 which delayed me from completing the exercise.

**Example 1 - Page 29 - Listing 2.4**

In the book it suggests that Installed Apps section of the settings.py file should be amended as per the below. 
in terminal.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'chapter2.first'
)
```

In my case the above would not work but the blow would.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'first'
)
```

In this case the error would not let me use the commands `python manage.py syncdb` or `python manage.py runserver` and returned the error

```
ImportError: No module named first
```

**Example 2 - Page 31 - Listing 2.9**

In the urls.py file the book instructs the user to use the following line of code

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
```

In my case the above did nto work but the below would

```
from django.conf.urls import *
```

In this case the server would run but a Django error page would be returned to the user with the error

```
ImportError at /
No module named defaults
```

I know there are some differences between Python 2.x and 3 but this book explicitly says on Page 3

> "Django works with Python 2.3 to 2.6 but not yet with the experimental
>   Python version 3, so we'll install version 2.6 for this book.

My setup

Mac OSX 10.9.2
Django 1.6.4
Python 2.7.5

Question Repeat: Can anyone tell me from these two examples what possible reasons there could be for these issues or are they just errors in the book?

Comment: If the book does not mention Python 2.7, that means its contents are at least four years old, and therefore cannot talk about Django newer than 1.2. We're close to 1.7 now…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's an outdated book. `django.conf.urls.defaults` has been deprecated (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/internals/deprecation/#id1)) in Django 1.6 and thus is no longer used.

Regarding the book itself, I'm not personally familiar with it, but the [Amazon reviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321643402) don't appear to be too positive. Further, using wildcard imports (i.e. `import *` in the `urls.py` is a pretty basic no-no in Python. See pep8 on imports [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports). That itself would make me wary of the book.

I'd recommend using the official Django tutorial (start [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/)) to get some background, as well as some other basic guides ([Tango with Django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/#) is another favorite). Then, once you've gotten your feet wet, get [Two Scoops of Django](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/098146730X), which is pretty much the go-to guide for Django best practices.

Comment: Thanks, I thought i was going mad there for a while not being able to get the examples working.